# integrating keycloak into angular project

Tags: keycloak-angular

guys, I want to integrate Keycloak into my Angular project but I found myself faced with this error TS1259 if there is anyone who has a solution please help
[this is a screen that shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIm0K.png)

[here is the function I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGD31.png)

[and this is the provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvg5N.png)

[I tried this function following a video on youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAKLD.png)

Comment: fixed  , in keycloak-angular/lib/services/keycloak.service.d.ts : switch from import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';   to import * as Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';